# SQL query to select latest 5 record as per respective user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables `Registration` & `Enquery`.

**Registration**:

```
Id  User_id     name      Phone         Address
------------------------------------------------
1   biz_1445    Ajinkya   5555555555    Delhi
2   biz_1256    Shubham   45698745      Mumbai
3   biz_2658    shikhar   523698        Nagpur
```

**Enquery**:

```
Enq_Id  enq_name         enq_details            user_id
---------------------------------------------------------
1       skycam           call for visit         biz_1445
2       websort          visit                  biz_2658
3       reliance         order of 100items      biz_1445    
4       Digital-Shoppe   enquire about 6 PC.    biz_1445
```

Basic working is: sales person enters the data through his app and it gets submitted into the `Enquery` table. Now I want to show latest 5 entries of the respective sales person and show it in recyclerview in my app. Can you help  me in SQL logic for that?

Comment: i'm using SQL Server @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know `user_id` of the person who submitted into **Enquery**.
suppose this id is call `current_user_id`.

So the query should be like -

```
select * 
from (
    select top 5 Enq_Id, enq_name, enq_details 
    from Enquery where user_id = current_user_id 
    order by Enq_Id desc
) a 
order by Enq_Id asc
```

Comment: It shows an error:"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '5 enq_id, enq_name, enq_details
    from enquery where user_id = current_user_' at line 3" @Faruk Hossain

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT reg.name,reg.Phone,reg.Address,enq.[user_id],enq.[Enq_Id]
    ,enq.enq_name
    ,enq.enq_details
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY enq.[user_id] ORDER BY enq.[Enq_Id] DESC) AS RNO
FROM [Enquery] enq
INNER JOIN [Registration] reg ON enq.[User_id] = reg.[User_id] ) A
WHERE RNO <= 5
```

Answer (score -3):

The SQL Query for Showing up 5 latest records of Sales Person:

```
return DB:table('Registration')->join('Enquery', 'Registration.User_id', 'Enquery.user_id')
 ->OrderBy('Enq_id', 'desc')
 ->where('Enquery.user_id', '=', 'Registration.User_id')
 ->distinct()
```

Comment: That's not a SQL query

Comment: Not an MySQL query